# What's the point of using JWTs with ASPNet.Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, token, bearer-token

I've implemented ASPNET.Identity with a custom JWTProvider. However is there a point of using JWT with ASPNET.Identity instead of the baked in regular token bearer in Identity already?  Does this increase security?  Does it just add more complexity to the application?

**UPDATE**
In terms of using the Oauth token provider vs custom JWTProvider.  Does this get you any added security?

Comment: What regular token bearer are you talking about? I thought ASP.Net Identity doesn't provide tokens, at least not in .Net Core.

Comment: Sorry the Oauth provider vs custom JWT provider.

Answer (score 2):

Both are very much different in terms of `XSRF/CSRF`.

In case of OAuth `XSRF` token is always send to client in every response header of server. It does not matter, `CSRF` token is sent in JWT token or not. Because `CSRF` token is secured with itself. Therefore sending CSRF token in JWT is unnecessary.

Comment: So are you saying there is absolutely no point in creating a custom JWTProvider in .NET because the OAuth handles this already?

Comment: Both are self sufficient with different working and architecture, its only your choice or business requirements that helps you decide which one you want to implement and ditch the other one.